# Push уведомления в приложениях для androida, может есть какие туториалы, статьи, примеры?

Tags: android, push-уведомления

Push уведомления в приложениях для androida, может есть какие туториалы, статьи, примеры (хотя бы приблизительные).

Answer (score 1):

Начать с официального сайта не пробовали? http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: Пробовала, но мне это мало.

Comment: Есть ещё официальное видео - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoaP6hcDctM

А чего конкретно не хватает?

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую приложуху, в ней есть визуальные примеры и код и ссылка на код, тех или иных визуальных эффектов.
Можно найти любой интересующий эффект, не только пуш. Попробуйте, не пожалеете.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=ru